# Extract subnetwork from network and do feedforward pass

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have a a simple fully connected neural network with `L` layers. Now I want to extract a part of that network, say from hidden layer `l` to hidden layer `l+n`. Now `l` is the input and `l+n` the output of this smaller subnetwork. I would like to use this smaller network to do a feedforward pass. Does Tensorflow provide any functions to do that or do I have to extract all weights to build a new network first?

EDIT:

To be more precise let's assume the following fully connected network:

```
1024 -> 512 -> 256 -> 128 -> 64 -> 32 -> 16
```

Where the numbers stand for the layer size of the respective layer. From this network I would like to extract the following part

```
256 -> 128 -> 64
```

to process data. This network has now an input layer and output layer of size 256 and 64, respectively.

Is there a simple way to accomplish that in Tensorflow?

Comment: What do you mean extract? You can freeze certain layers from getting trained but you shouldn't freeze input layers

Answer (score 0):

Using `tensorflow.keras.layers` you can use `model.layers.pop()` to remove last layer of the model.
You can also stop training of the model using,

```
for layer in model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
```

Also you can add your model as part of another model,

```
new_model = models.Sequential()
new_model.add(model)
#rest of the code.
```

Edit: OP is asking about Tensorflow, so using tensorflow distribution.

Comment: OP asked for tensorflow, you have assumed the use of keras.

Comment: Keras is official high level API of Tensorflow. Editing my code.

Comment: Yes, not necessary he didn't mention the use of keras. You may use tf without keras.

Comment: @LazyCoder Keras is part of tf. When someone say I can us tf, I can assume he can use tensorflow.keras.

Comment: I do not see how your answer answers my question. I therefore updated my question.